# How do I tag a html-document to show when the document was created / updated?

Tags: html, tags, meta, author, web-search

Is there a standard for tagging a html document with create date and modified date?

Ketil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're willing to use Schema.org microdata, you could use [dateCreated](https://schema.org/dateCreated) and [dateModified](https://schema.org/dateModified).

Something like this:

```
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">
    <p>
        Created on <time itemprop="dateCreated" datetime="2014-12-29T04:19:22">December 29th, 2014</time>
    </p>
</body>
```